# Запись результатов парсинга в CSV файл

Tags: python, парсер, csv

Начал изучать парсинг сайтов на Python.
Могу спарсить данные и вывести их на экран. В окне терминала все выглядит идеально. Но если допустим эти данные отправлять клиенту, то ему эти данные скорее всего нужны будут в виде файла. Пытаюсь записать результаты в CSV файл, но не получается. То либо только последняя строка записывается в файл в единственной строке,  то либо в нужном количестве строк, но на все строки опять же дублируется последняя запись. Чую, что где то близко, но в голову ничего пока не лезет.

Нужно записать результат парсинга в CSV файл. Первый столбец это номер по порядку, второй - наименование товара, третий - цена в тенге.

Вот код (в коде есть мусорные вещи, но это либо остатки поиска вариантов либо остатки от кода с пагинацией):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from csv import writer



headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/90.0.4480.84 (Edition Yx 08)'
   
}  

params = {'page': 1}
# задаем число больше номера первой страницы, для старта цикла
pages = 20  # количество страниц
page = 1    # номер начальной страницы
n = 1       # Начало нумерации


url = 'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy?page=1'    # делаем запрос на страницу
response = requests.get(url)                        # обработка запроса метотдом get
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')         # создаем суп
items = soup.find_all('li', class_='tile-container')# разбираем ячейки товара

    
if page <= pages: # Если текущая страница меньше или равно количеству страниц всего
    for n, i in enumerate(items, start=n):      # задаем нумерацию для всех ячеек
        itemName = i.find('h3', class_='title').text.replace("Смартфон", "").strip() # делаем выборку из супа. Тут в теге ищем клас с названием класса
        itemPrice = i.find('div', class_='price')  # Ищем второе значение
        if itemPrice is None:                   # Обработчик, если вдруг нет искомого класса или тега во втором значении
            itemPrice = 'No Price'         # 
        else:
            itemPrice = itemPrice.text.replace("Цена:", "").replace("₸", "").strip() # Удаляем лишний текст и переносы 
      
        Index = n
        GoodName = itemName
        Price = itemPrice

        print(Index, GoodName, Price)   # Выводим на экран список товаров
        
       

        with open("Goods_Sulpak.csv", mode="w", newline = '', encoding='cp1251') as w_file:
            file_writer = csv.writer(w_file, delimiter = ";", lineterminator="\r")
            file_writer.writerow(["Index", "Good Name", "Price"])
            for Index, GoodName, Price in items:
                file_writer.writerow([n, itemName, itemPrice])
```

Пагинация тоже работает и весь массив данных со всех страниц собирается надо.
[image: Результат парсинга в окне терминала]

[image: Результат парсинга в файле]

Comment: Вы сначала данные в список словарей соберите, потом один раз в самом конце используйте `csv.DictWriter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
              'Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/90.0.4480.84 (Edition Yx 08) '
}

params = {'page': 1}
# задаем число больше номера первой страницы, для старта цикла
pages = 20  # количество страниц
page = 1  # номер начальной страницы
n = 1  # Начало нумерации

# создаем csv документ с нужными столбцами
with open('Goods_Sulpak.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fil:
    writer = csv.writer(fil)
    writer.writerow((
        "Индекс",
        "Наименование",
        "Стоимость"
    ))

url = 'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy?page=1'  # делаем запрос на страницу
response = requests.get(url)  # обработка запроса метотдом get
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')  # создаем суп
items = soup.find_all('li', class_='tile-container')  # разбираем ячейки товара

if page <= pages:  # Если текущая страница меньше или равно количеству страниц всего
    for n, i in enumerate(items, start=n):  # задаем нумерацию для всех ячеек
        itemName = i.find('h3', class_='title').text.replace("Смартфон",
                                                             "").strip()  # делаем выборку из супа. Тут в теге ищем клас с названием класса
        itemPrice = i.find('div', class_='price')  # Ищем второе значение
        if itemPrice is None:  # Обработчик, если вдруг нет искомого класса или тега во втором значении
            itemPrice = 'No Price'  #
        else:
            itemPrice = itemPrice.text.replace("Цена:", "").replace("₸", "").strip()  # Удаляем лишний текст и переносы

        Index = n
        GoodName = itemName
        Price = itemPrice

        print(Index, GoodName, Price)  # Выводим на экран список товаров

        # записываем полученные данные в csv построчно
        with open('Goods_Sulpak.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fil:
            writer = csv.writer(fil)
            writer.writerow((
                Index,
                GoodName,
                Price
            ))
```

Comment: О отлично. Все как надо.  Единственное в  writer = csv.writer(fil) внес изменения, добавил изменение разделителя, вместо запятой точку с запятой. writer = csv.writer(fil, delimiter = ";") . Если стоит запятая, то эксель данные показывает, построчно, но все столбцы в один столбец в первой ячейке. И еще изменил кодировку с utf-8 на cp1251, потому что в экселе вместо кириллицы кракозябры.

Comment: Ну. это уж как вам угодно ) В Linux все нормально, да и в LibreOffice если открыть - тоже.

Comment: @ВикторКалгин, измените кодировку на `utf-8-sig`

Comment: @Namerek
Спасибо за подсказку с кодировкой. Заменил, все работает.

Answer (score 2):

На правах варианта реализации:
`pip install fake-useragent requests tqdm pydantic bs4`

```py
from typing import List
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from requests import Session
from tqdm import tqdm

u_agent = UserAgent()

s = Session()
s.headers.update(

    {'User-Agent': u_agent.firefox}

)

base_url = 'https://www.sulpak.kz'


class Good(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(alias='Index')
    name: str = Field(alias='Good Name')
    price: float = Field(0, alias='Price')

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        validate_assignment = True

    @classmethod
    def fields(cls):
        return list(cls.schema(by_alias=True).get('properties').keys())


goods: List[Good] = []


def process_page(page=1):
    # noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
    response = s.get(
        base_url + '/f/smartfoniy',
        params={
            'page': page
        }
    )
    soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    total_pages = int(
        paginator.get('data-pagescount') if (
            paginator := soup.find(
                'div', {'class': 'pagination'}
            )
        ) else 1
    )

    for item in soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'tile-container'}):
        good = Good(
            id=item.get('data-code'),
            name=item.get('data-name')
        )

        if price := item.get('data-price'):
            good.price = price

        goods.append(
            good
        )
    return total_pages


for p in tqdm(range(2, (pages := process_page()) + 1), initial=1, total=pages):
    process_page(p)

with open('result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=Good.fields(), dialect=csv.excel)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(
        [
            item.dict(by_alias=True) for item in goods
        ]
    )
# 100%|██████████| 19/19 [00:08<00:00,  2.14it/s]
```

Вариант для пошустрее:

> Правда на 19-ти страницах так-себе прирост скорости но "чтобы было"

```py
# В импорт добавляем
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

# Дальше здесь оcтальной код без изменения до цикла

with Pool(8) as pool:
    for _ in tqdm(
            pool.imap_unordered(
                process_page, 
                range(
                    2, 
                    (pages := process_page()) + 1)
            ), 
            initial=1, 
            total=pages
    ):
        pass
# 100%|██████████| 19/19 [00:02<00:00,  6.02it/s]
# Запись в файл тоже не меняется
```

> *Не стоит злоупотреблять с многопоточнгостью при парсинге ибо забанят нафиг с гарантией в 95%*

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал твой код. Вроде работает без ошибок, но немного не так как мне надо. 1. Почему то отказывается читать последнюю страницу сайта. У тебя 100% и 19 из 19 страниц, у меня процесс завершается на 95%  и 18 из 19 страниц. 2. Индексы, у меня выходят шестизначные числа непонятной последовательности, вместо чисел по порядку.

Comment: @ВикторКалгин,  Относительно кода выше: Как написано в самом начале, это не ответ это вариант реализации. Насчет индексов: "шестизначные числа непонятной последовательности" это артикулы товаров. Как думаешь, что произойдет если перейти по ссылке `https://www.sulpak.kz/g/{артикул товара из моего парсера}`?. Ты перейдешь на страницу товара, и поэтому для того, чтобы, к примеру, проследить обновление цены на конкретный товар, тебе не нужно его будет опять парсить через поиск.

Comment: @ВикторКалгин, `for p in tqdm(range(2, (pages := process_page()) + 1), initial=1, total=pages):` цикл вот так напишите. а то у вас счетчик бара пропускает первый вызов функции где количество страниц считается. Ответ тоже поправил

Comment: Спасибо. В 41 не так просто все это дается - изучать программирование.

Comment: @ВикторКалгин, знаю, сам такой ) `https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/` вот тут много полезного по стандартной библиотеке.

Answer (score 0):

Вот финальный код, где применен ответ Johan с перебором заданного диапазона страниц

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
              'Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/90.0.4480.84 (Edition Yx 08) '
}

params = {'page': 1}
# задаем число больше номера первой страницы, для старта цикла
pages = 20  # количество страниц
page = 1  # номер начальной страницы
n = 1  # Начало нумерации


    # создаем csv документ с нужными столбцами
with open('Goods_Sulpak.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as fil:
    writer = csv.writer(fil, delimiter = ";")
    writer.writerow((
        "Индекс",
        "Наименование",
        "Стоимость"
    ))

while True:
    url = 'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy?page=' + str(page)   # делаем запрос на страницу
    response = requests.get(url)  # обработка запроса методом get
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')  # создаем суп
    items = soup.find_all('li', class_='tile-container')  # разбираем ячейки товара

    if page <= pages:  # Если текущая страница меньше или равно количеству страниц всего
        for n, i in enumerate(items, start=n):  # задаем нумерацию для всех ячеек
            itemName = i.find('h3', class_='title').text.replace("Смартфон",
                                                                 "").strip()  # делаем выборку из супа. Тут в теге ищем класс с названием класса
            itemPrice = i.find('div', class_='price')  # Ищем второе значение
            if itemPrice is None:  # Обработчик, если вдруг нет искомого класса или тега во втором значении
                itemPrice = 'No Price'  #
            else:
                itemPrice = itemPrice.text.replace("Цена:", "").replace("₸", "").strip()  # Удаляем лишний текст и переносы

            Index = n
            GoodName = itemName
            Price = itemPrice

            print(Index, GoodName, Price)  # Выводим на экран список товаров

            # записываем полученные данные в csv построчно
            with open('Goods_Sulpak.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as fil:
                writer = csv.writer(fil, delimiter = ";")
                writer.writerow((
                    Index,
                    GoodName,
                    Price
                ))

        page += 1   # Прибавляем каждый цикл единицу к текущей странице
    else:           # Если достигли последней страницы, то завершаем цикл.
        break
```